# Sorting based on a sub key value in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort a list of objects from firebase based on the value of sub key but seems failed. I used the filter `ref.orderByChild('sort_order')` but the data returned is not in the sorted format. Giving below my node structure and can someone help me to point out where I went wrong ?

```
"widgets":{
  "fruits":{
    "sort_order":"2",
    "data":[{
    "thread_id":"201902001",
    "source_port":"Shanghai",
    "source_port_latitude":"31.218399",
    "source_port_longitude":"121.434563",
    "destination_port":"Singapore",
    "destination_port_latitude":"1.32046",
    "destination_port_longitude":"103.72042",
    "created_on":"2019-02-01 01:02:03"
  }]
},
  "vegetables":{
    "sort_order":"1",
    "data":[{
      "thread_id":"201902004",
      "source_port":"Jebel Ali",
      "source_port_latitude":"24.99626",
      "source_port_longitude":"55.12536",
      "destination_port":"Port Klang",
      "destination_port_latitude":"2.999852",
      "destination_port_longitude":"101.39283",
      "created_on":"2019-02-04 10:11:12"
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly was the order, if not what you expected?  Bear mind that the values of "sort_order" appears to be strings rather than numbers.

Comment: It should be `vegetables` first and then `fruits`

Comment: It works for me though: https://jsbin.com/zaguyad/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the problem with your data. For my working code, see https://jsbin.com/zaguyad/edit?js,console.

The most likely cause of the problems is how you handle the data that your query returns. The proper way to maintain ordering information is by using `DataSnapshot.forEach()`:

```
ref.child("widgets").orderByChild('sort_order')
  .once('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
      console.log(child.key);
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thats was the issue. Instead of `DataSnapshot.forEach()` I tried to console `snapshot.val()`. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear Tismon. For future questions though, please always include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it drastically increases the chances that someone (aside from me) can answer.